# conflict between click.funcion and bootstraps' carousel buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootsraps carousel and smooth scrolling with jquery.

Here is how I make smooth scrolling:

```
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

I assumed this code prevents functions of carousel buttons. How can I modify it in a way that it doesnt affects carousel buttons.

Note that I am complete beginner at web development.

Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific about parent of `a` to avoid carousel wrapper

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you can do one of two things:

1. [Namespace](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/) the smooth scroll click event to avoid conflicts with
   the carousel.

   E.g. `$('a').on('click.scroll', function() {…})`
2. Allow [event propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) in the smooth scroll function by removing `return false;`

Hope that helps!